# Blue light filter for Mac

Tags: osx, display

I have this [Bluelight Filter for Eye Care](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.hardyinfinity.bluelightfilter.free&hl=en) tool on my phone, which is really useful because I think blue light does keep me awake.

I'm wondering if there is a similar app on the Mac?

It would be preferable if it was set on some sort of timer which would automatically turn on the filter after say 11 pm and turn it off in the morning.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know,  [F.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) is recommended largely to filter blue light emitted from computer screen. It can make your computer color automatically changed by the time of day. At the same time, you can search other blue light filter app for your smartphone or Windows computer.

There is a nice article to introduce top free blue light blocking apps to improve your sleep: http://www.taimeopt.com/top-blue-light-filter-apps-help-sleep-better/

Hope it helps!